# Batch command to move many folders inside an alfabetic directory structure

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, directory

I have this content inside a directory

```
[FOLDERS]
Atomic
Animal
Cat
flash
Zoe

[FILES]
text.txt
audio.rar
```

I want to reorder moving folders inside an alfabetic directory structure like this (case is irrilevant). I want move only folders no files

```
A [Atomic, Animal]
C [cat]
f [flash]
Z [zoe]
file1.rar
file2.txt
```

where A,C,f,Z are parent folders. Folders in bracket are MOVED folders not CONSOLIDATED folders! 
Which **.bat** command can I use?

I want move inside a unique folder called *A* for all folders that starts with ***A*** letter. For folders that starts with *F* letter I want move them in a single folder called ***F*** 
Moving is not replacing or merging because I assume that all folders that starts with same letter have different names, I want simply order them by first folder letters. 

 I don't want consolidate folders in unique folders by letter but only ***moving*** in unique folder by first folder letter.

[WHAT I WANT](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/reorder_folder_by_first_letter.htm)

Comment: Just to confirm. Do you want to change the folder name from `Afolder1` to `A` and so on?

Comment: What about `Afolder1` and `Afolder2`? Overwrite? Merge their contents? What if there are duplicate file names inside the two (or more) folders?

Comment: @Eric S no, I don't want rename but just move or copy folders inside an alphabetic folders order by first folder letter. X Stephan no, i don't want merge and i do not overwrite folders but only move inside a unique folder called *A* for all folders that starts with ***A*** letter. For folders that starts with *F* letter I want move them in a single folder called ***F***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem md atomic animal cat flash zoe alfa american banda barca beta brasil cane alfa\subdir
tree
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  set first=!first:~0,1!
  md !first! 2>nul
  if not "!first!" == "%%i" move "%%i" "!first!\%%i" 
)
tree
```

for every directory in the current folder do: 
- get the first letter 
- create the one letter folder 
- if the folder isn't a one letter folder, move it.

use `tree` to show the result

Comment: Some instruction is wrong because copy only one folder inside alphabetic structure, look here: [REORDER](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/reorder_folder_by_first_letter.htm)

Comment: sorry, the "one letter folder" has to exist before moving. See my edited code.

Comment: thanks for correction, but is there a method to create automatically this list?  In some situation i can have 100-200 directories with folders inside so I can't write all folders names inside all folders within, It would be annoying..

Comment: But if I have folder name with spaces like "star wars"? how can I wite? `rem md atomic animal "star wars" zoe alfa\subdir` ?

Comment: this works fine with spaces in folder names. `rem` stands for `remark` this means, this line is a comment. I used the `md <list of folders>` to create an environment to work with (and commented it out but didn't remove it so other readers are able to create the same environment.) And yes, quotes are the way to `md "folder with spaces"`