# Batch - Append folder list automatically inside specific position in main code

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to reorder folders inside an alphabetic order but for make this I must adding list manually inside my code and I want to automate this task. If I have one directory there would not be this problem but the situation is that I have to manage many many numerous folders inside which there are numerous other folders. 
This condition makes it necessary to prepare these lists automatically. How to integrate this task?

Inside a directory I have these folders

```
alfa
atomic
cat
flash
zoe
```

I want to move them reordering using an alphabetic order. To process this I use this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem md atomic animal cat flash zoe alfa american banda barca beta brasil cane alfa\subdir
tree
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  set first=!first:~0,1!
  md !first! 2>nul
  if not "!first!" == "%%i" move "%%i" "!first!\%%i" 
)
tree
```

What is the problem?
I have many directories with 100-200 folders within  so I really can't copy and paste all these names.
I need an automatic ***.bat*** script that 'append' this automatic list inside my main code so - when it creating folder list - folders are moved with no problem.
If I don't create before this list, for example in my code is

```
rem md atomic animal cat flash zoe alfa american banda barca beta brasil cane alfa\subdir
```

script doesn't work well.

Alternative code simply is this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  move "%%i" "!first:~0,1!"
)
```

However also in this situation ***I must create a folder list *before* like this if I want to move folders inside this list***

```
A
C
F
Z
```

. 
But for my real condition I have many directories, so why I should spend time to create 100++ folders name manually like ***A, B,C,D,E,F,G***...before I can use my script? 
 
Why do I need to do two steps? 
Is there an automatically solution to append this automatic lists?

Comment: All files and folders are stored in alphabetical order in NTFS file system. This is so it can use binary search algorithms which are quick to find files. Therefore you do not need to worry about ordering.

Comment: I want to reorder folders inside an alphabetic order but for make this I must adding list manually inside my code and I and I want to automate this task. If I have one directory there would not be this problem but the situation is that I have to manage numerous folders with many inside them.

Comment: They are and always will be, no matter what you do, alphabetical. You can't change it. Therefore your problem is nothing to do with ordering of files. Restate what your problem is by editing your post.

Comment: correct post with notes. Now is ok? Are you understand?

Comment: Restate your problem having regard to their being NO ALPHABETICAL ORDERING problem. Everything will be alphabetical. But it's unclear with all the talk of alphabetical what end point you want and what problem you are having. You certainly won't need to type 100's of things.

Comment: yes, ***It is what I'm saying***. The problem is to move the folders do not reorder them. But as I write it is not enough just move them, but we need to create a list of folders before if I wanted then actually move them inside this list.Where I write that it is a problem related to the need to reorder the folders in alphabetical order?

Comment: you don't need to do anything manual. `md !first!` creates the single-letter-folder for you, if needed. `2>nul` merely supresses the error message if this folder already exists.

Comment: uhm..I try now to eliminate your part code `rem md atomic animal cat flash zoe alfa american banda barca beta brasil cane alfa\subdir` and seems to be ok. @Stephan..I am confused with that part of code. Why did you include?

Comment: I told you in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409228/batch-command-to-move-many-folders-inside-an-alfabetic-directory-structure#comment60470820_36411449)

Comment: ah.ha..I had passed beyond this your passage .. `and commented it out but didn't remove it so other readers are able to create the same environment`..sorry Stephan