# Batch: Move Folders by initial letter to A-Z folder structure - in alphabetical order starting with A

Tags: sorting, for-loop, batch-file, directory

My question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409228/batch-command-to-move-many-folders-inside-an-alfabetic-directory-structure).

I have a folder with the following subfolders:

```
├───ABC 
├───AKL akl
├───AYZ ayz
├───BCD bcd BCD
├───BYZ
└───CYZ
```

and I'd like to have it resorted to:

```
├───A
│   ├───ABC
│   ├───AKL akl
│   └───AYZ ayz
├───B
│   ├───BCD bcd BCD
│   └───BYZ
├───C
│   └───CYZ
```

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36411449/2605073)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
tree
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  set first=!first:~0,1!
  md !first! 2>nul
  if not "!first!" == "%%i" move "%%i" "!first!\%%i" 
)
tree
```

does the job. However, the resorting does not necessarily start at the letter "A". I do not know how the order in the loop is determined, but sometimes it starts at an arbitrary letter. So my question is:

**How can I process the source folders in alphabetical order - starting at A?** I require to create the new folders "A" to "Z" in alphabetical order and fill them alphabetically, starting at "A".

***Background**: The folders are folders of music artists on an usb drive which should be resorted. The multimedia system in the car does not show the folders on the drive in alphabetically order, but without any clear logic. It is also not enough to just copy the artist folders in the correct order. But creating the alphabetical subfolders in the correct order will (hopefully) at least show the letters in the correct order later in the car.*

Comment: Your stick is probably a FATxx file system. It stores the files in no particular order. NTFS sorts them alphabetically. Change to `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b /on *') do ...` to let `dir` do the sorting.

Comment: When your destination folder on the stick is empty, the files should be in the order they were written. If you delete a single file, there is a "hole" in the allocation table, that the next copied file will fill, ruining your order.

Comment: @Stephan your solution works, you could make it an answer an maybe explain a little?
Regarding your other comment: weirdly enough, even full formatting the stick and copying the artist folders in alphabetical order by using a third party tool, does not solve the issue. The order is influenced by the novelty of the playlist in my pc music player (MusicBee), which is the basis for the artist folders. It makes no sense.

Comment: FAT is an old concept (dating back to the nineteen-seventies) [It actually seemed logical to us then](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/file-allocation-table-fat#:~:text=File%20Allocation%20Table%20(FAT)%20is%20a%20file%20system%20used%20by,physical%20location%20on%20the%20disk.). Nowadays this concept seems weird.

Comment: @Stephan I actually mean, that the car does not care about the allocation table, because then sorting tools like drivesort should do the job, or a least formatting and organized copying. But from side of the car's OS there must be some weird additional logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage media mounted as removable drive via USB is obviously using [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) or [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) as file system.

Microsoft offers among many others following related documentations:

- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)
- [Overview of FAT, HPFS, and NTFS File Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/backup-and-storage/fat-hpfs-and-ntfs-file-systems)
- [File System Functionality Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison)
- [exFAT file system specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification)
- [How FAT Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc776720(v=ws.10))
- [NTFS overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/ntfs-overview)
- [How NTFS Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781134(v=ws.10))

The file system FAT32 does not add file system entries to the file allocation table in a *local specific alphabetic* order as NTFS does on updating the master file table. The file system entries (directory and file names) are added by FAT32 to the file allocation table by appending it at the end of the table resulting in new directory/file name appended at the bottom or using the first free entry in the existing table of a directory resulting in new directory/file name inserted anywhere within the table.

A program just processing the list of file system entries as returned by the file system processes therefore directories and files on FAT32 formatted storage medias in a not ordered manner. The internal command **FOR** of the *Windows Command Processor* processes files (without using option `/D`) and directories (with using option `/D`) one after the other as returned by the file system.
See also: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975093/at-which-point-does-for-or-for-r-enumerate-the-directory-tree)

There can be used a command like **DIR** with option `/ON` for getting the list of subdirectories in a directory **ordered by name** using a simple **alphabetic** sort. The list returned by **DIR** with option `/ON` is not the same as NTFS returns if directories and files contain non-ASCII characters like `ÄÖÜäöü` often used in German because of `Ää` is not interpreted like `Aa`, `Öö` like `Oo`, and `Üü` like `Uu` by **DIR**. The list is also not the same as *Windows File Explorer* shows with its ***alphanumeric*** sort. The directories `Directory1`, `Directory2`, `Directory3` ... `Directory10`, `Directory11`, `Directory12` are listed by **DIR** with using `/ON` in the order `Directory1`, `Directory10`, `Directory11`, `Directory12`, `Directory2`, `Directory3` ...

The batch file below moves the folders in the **current directory** with a name with more than one character into a directory which name is the first character.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "*!*" goto ExtendedFolderMove
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V /X "."') do set "FolderName=%%I" & md "!FolderName:~0,1!" 2>nul & move "!FolderName!" "!FolderName:~0,1!\" >nul
endlocal
goto EndBatch

:ExtendedFolderMove
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V /X "."') do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "DestinationFolder=!FolderName:~0,1!"
    md "!DestinationFolder!" 2>nul
    move "!FolderName!" "!DestinationFolder!\" >nul
    endlocal
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The batch file processes just directories including directories with hidden attribute set and ignores directory links although hard links, symbolic links and directory junctions are not supported by FAT32 at all.

**FINDSTR** is used for filtering out all directory names with just one character by using a regular expression (`/R`) searching for an entire line `/X` having any character (`"."`) and outputs all lines (= directory names) inverted (`/V`) which means with more than one character.

The batch file first checks if a file system entry (directory or file name) in the **current directory** contains `!` in which case the extended version for moving the folder is used by the batch file. [Delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) of variables causes a second parsing of the command line `set "FolderName=%%I"` by `cmd.exe` after `%%I` is replaced by the current directory name interpreting an exclamation mark now as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference. The one command line solution does not work for that reason for a directory name with one or more `!` in name.

The extended solution is a bit slower because of `setlocal` and `endlocal` must be used now inside the loop for each directory name after having assigned the folder name to the environment variable `FolderName`. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** and what is done by `cmd` in background in memory on each execution of these two commands.

There can be used also the following batch file with ignoring all directories with just a single character by using an **IF** condition with a string comparison.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "*!*" goto ExtendedFolderMove
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B /ON 2^>nul') do set "FolderName=%%I" & if not "!FolderName:~2!" == "" md "!FolderName:~0,1!" 2>nul & move "!FolderName!" "!FolderName:~0,1!\" >nul
endlocal
goto EndBatch

:ExtendedFolderMove
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "DestinationFolder=!FolderName:~0,1!"
    if not "!DestinationFolder!" == "!FolderName!" (
        md "!DestinationFolder!" 2>nul
        move "!FolderName!" "!DestinationFolder:~0,1!\" >nul
    )
    endlocal
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

However, there is no guarantee that on the USB connected storage media the file allocation table contains now really `A`, `B`, `C` ... for the main directory and the subdirectories inside `A` or `B` or `C` ... are all in alphabetic order. The user has no real control over the order of file system entries in the file allocation table, except using a special FAT sorting tool.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on the **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes these command lines before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.